# App request notification sending failed on facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am new in Iphone and stuck here in facebook application , In fact I am getting list of all of my facebook friends with their id's in my TableView. When I tab on table view I want to send notification to my friend, dialoge is showing , when i press the send button, facebook dialoge disappear, and my friend don't receive the notification. Can you help me please. Here is my code,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString* kAppId = @"317060778330475";
    Facebook *faceBook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];
    NSDictionary *dic = [facebookInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *friendId = [dic valueForKey:@"id"];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hi check my application, please!",  @"message",
                                   friendId, @"to",
                                   nil];
    [faceBook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params  andDelegate:self];
}

#pragma mark - Facebook Delegates 

- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog {

    NSLog(@"App Request Sent!");
}
- (void)dialogCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"Urls is :%@",url);
}
```